# Should there be another tag for vector bundles in Algebraic geometry (over schemes)?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should there be another tag for vector bundles in Algebraic geometry (over schemes)?

[Some](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343060/zero-section-of-quasi-coherent-bundle) [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342897/global-section-module-of-algebraic-vector-bundles-on-the-punctured-spectrum-of-a) [about](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/341627/beauville-laszlo-for-schemes) vector bundles in the sense of algebraic geometry are given the [tag](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/vector-bundles) whose [tag description](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/vector-bundles/info) says

> A continuously varying family of vector spaces of the same dimension over a topological space. If the vector spaces are one-dimensional, the term line bundle is used and has the associated tag line-bundles.

So, the question is, is it a better idea to create another tag for vector bundles in the sense of algebraic geometry?

Comment: I agree with S. Carnahan's answer. Multiplication of tags is results in a less coherent use and sets up artificial boundaries (differential and algebraic geometry are not disjoint settings). I'd even say that the fact the tag vector-bundles is transversal to those subjects makes it valuable. That some people reading the tag vector-bundles have difficulty with understanding those posts in algebraic geometry is part of the game.

Comment: @YCor “That some people reading the tag vector-bundles have difficulty with understanding those posts in algebraic geometry is part of the game”.. thank you.. :) every time you respond, it teach me something..

Comment: I actually include myself among these "some people" (not for this particular tag which I don't subscribe, but many others). And also in congresses/seminars I attend which are supposedly in "my" field. This is part of student/researcher's life. If a subtopic is broad it's normal not to understand all its aspects, no shame.

Comment: Yes, master.. no shame :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think a new tag is necessary here.  Usually, we want a new tag when a single term is used in quite different ways in different fields.  Here, the concepts are essentially the same - in both topological and schematic settings, you can define vector bundles in terms of structure morphisms and the existence of a trivialization by open cover.

There may be some merit to revising the tag info.

Comment: I am thinking people who can comfortably think of vector bundles in the set up of manifolds has difficulty in seeing them in algebraic geometry... Am I misunderstanding? Just adding the term "over a scheme" might not make much difference..